# Possible to group auto mapper create maps?

Tags: automapper

I have something like this

```
public static class RegisterMaps
{

    public static void Register()
    {
        // Mapper.Create
    }
}
```

I am noticing now that I have so many Maps that is it getting quite out of hand. I am wondering is there away to group them together so they are easier to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Profiles](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/15/automapper-profiles.aspx).  They should help you out.